Removing sliding glass door panel
How do I get it out without damaging it?



To remove the sliding panel on one of my sliding glass doors I first lower the door slightly by retracting the two roller units into the door at the bottom. Then lift the door and swing out the bottom past the threshold.  Retracting the rollers to lower the door might not be necessary in all types, but this gives increased clearance at the top allowing the door to be raised high enough for the roller edges to clear the rails on which they ride.

Look inside that notch at the bottom of the door.  Might see a screwhead that is meant for height adjustment.  If so, there will be a second one on the other end/side.

It would be much better to use the built in image hosting, since SE's contract with imgur has ended and they're moving away from them.

Always do top and sides first.   Can you slide a thin mud knife through all 3?   If not get rid of trim and get the saw out to bust the nails.

check the top track ... there may be tabs that allow lifting only when the door is fully open

Moved images into SE's system for inline display.

Look for adjustment screws at the top and bottom corners and loosen them all , then lift the door/panel and move the bottom off the track first.
